# Using the externalDs field for a Person in People API, working in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-people-api

This is probably a dumb question, and if so I apologize. I have searched here and on Google and can't find an answer.

I want to be able to modify the externalIds field for a Person. I'm able to modify other fields like names. Generally like:

```
let query = "John Doe";
let found = People.People.searchContacts({
  "query": query,
  "readMask": "names"
});
let thisResult = found.results[0];
thisResult.person.names[0].familyName = "Smith";
People.People.updateContact(thisResult.person, thisResult.person.resourceName, {updatePersonFields: "names"});
```

I can't figure out how this works with externalIds though. Trying to modify thisResult.person.externalIDs[0] results in undefined. Also, I'm not clear what is meant by [predefined types](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.ExternalId). Isn't type just another string field within an externalId object, like familyName is in a name object? What would prevent multiple externalIds from having the same type?

Anyway, after much frustration I've been able to find no documentation on this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally happens when the person object doesn't contain any values under `externalIds` you can try this modification that will add the specified externalId object to the contact:

```
function myFunction() {
  let query = "John Doe";
  let found = People.People.searchContacts({
    "query": query,
    "readMask": "externalIds"
  });
  let thisResult = found.results[0];
  var externalId = { value: "AN_ID",type: "account" };
  var resourceToUpdate = {
    externalIds: externalId,
    etag: thisResult.person.etag
  };
  People.People.updateContact(resourceToUpdate, thisResult.person.resourceName, { updatePersonFields: "externalIds" });
}
```

Or you could use this version to just add a new `externalId` instead of overwriting them:

```
function myFunction() {
  let query = "John Doe";
  let found = People.People.searchContacts({
    "query": query,
    "readMask": "externalIds"
  });
  let thisResult = found.results[0];
  var externalId = { value: "AN_ID", type: "account" };

  if (thisResult.person.externalIds) {
    thisResult.person.externalIds.push(externalId);
    var resourceToUpdate = thisResult.person;

  } else {
    var resourceToUpdate = {
      externalIds: externalId,
      etag: thisResult.person.etag
    };
  }

  People.People.updateContact(resourceToUpdate, thisResult.person.resourceName, { updatePersonFields: "externalIds" });
}
```

Note that:

- While testing I could see that if you use a `predefined` type it will update its formattedType value, for example, using `loginId` will change it to `Login ID`, for non-predefined types it will automatically be assigned to the same value as `type`.
- You can have more than one externalId with a predefined type or use the same custom type more than once:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful and clearly written, thank you. After working with this for awhile, I believe you can also add a new userDefined field when some are aleady existing by doing:  

 let newUserDefinedValue = { key: "test1", value: "696969" };
      resource = {
        userDefined: [...person.userDefined, newUserDefinedValue],
        etag: person.etag
      };
  People.People.updateContact(resource, person.resourceName, 
                            { updatePersonFields: "userDefined" });

Comment: I asked basically the same question about userDefined in another thread. Between your help and the help I got there I was able to a useful utility function for writing to userDefined by key. I think externalID works basically the same way, so I thought you might be interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76448947/add-a-userdefined-field-to-a-person-from-a-google-apps-script/76449765?noredirect=1#comment134808558_76449765