# Add a userDefined field to a Person from a Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-people-api

**UPDATE**
After help from Tanaike and much playing around, I wrote the following functions to assist with writing a userDefined field specified by key. Maybe they'll be useful to someone. Feel free to tell me how they could be improved.

Next I'm going to try to modify this to work with the Person.externalID fields instead.

```
/**
 * Writes a userDefined field to a Person based on the key:
 *  If the Person has no userDefined fields, add a field.
 *  If they have some, search for the key and overwrite the value.
 *  If they have some and the key doesn't exist, add a field.
 *  If multiple fields with the key exist, display a warning dialog and exit.
 * @param {People.Person} person
 * @param {userDefined} People.person.userDefined
 */
function writeUserDefined(person, newUserDefinedValue){
  let resource;
  if (!person.userDefined)
  {
    Logger.log("   no keys exists");
    Logger.log("   adding new userDefined resource");  
    resource = {
      userDefined: [newUserDefinedValue],
      etag: person.etag
    };
  }
  else if(person.userDefined)
  {
    //if key exists
    index = getIndexUserDefined(person, newUserDefinedValue.key);
    if(index >= 0){
      Logger.log("   key exists");
      Logger.log("   modifying existing field at " + index);
      person.userDefined[index] = newUserDefinedValue;
      resource = person;
    }

    //if key doesn't exist
    else if (index === -1) {
      Logger.log("   key doesn't exist");
      Logger.log("   adding key to end" + index);
      resource = {
        userDefined: [...person.userDefined, newUserDefinedValue],
        etag: person.etag
      };
    }

    //multiple matching keys exist
    else if (index === -2) {
      Logger.log("   multiple keys exist");
      Logger.log("   displaying warning dialog" + index);
      resource = person;
      showMultipleCustomerIDsAlert(person.names[0].displayName);

    }
  }
  else { Logger.log("nothingburger"); return; }
  People.People.updateContact(resource, person.resourceName, 
                            { updatePersonFields: "userDefined" });
}

/**
 * Finds the index in person.userDefined[] of a field containing a specified key
 *  If no userDefined field with the key exists, returns -1
 *  If multiple fields with the key exists, returns -2
 *  Otherwise returns the index of the field with the key.
 * @param {People.person} person
 * @param {String} key
 * @return {Number} getIndexUserDefined
 */
function getIndexUserDefined(person,key){
  let index = -1;
  for(i=0; i < person.userDefined.length; i++){
    if( person.userDefined[i].key === key && index > -1 ){ 
      return -2; 
    }
    else if( person.userDefined[i].key === key && index == -1 ){
      index = i;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'm trying to use People.userDefined to store an ID number for contacts. However, unless a custom field has already been added from the Contacts app, I'm unable to add one in a script.

This works fine for a contact that already has a custom field created in the app:

```
let query = "Joe Smith"; 
var found = People.People.searchContacts(
  { 
    "query": query,   
    "readMask": "names,userDefined"
  }); 
thisResult = found.results[0];     
thisResult.person.userDefined[1].key = "HandymanCustID"; 
thisResult.person.userDefined[1].value = "0066"; 
People.People.updateContact(thisResult.person, thisResult.person.resourceName, 
                            {updatePersonFields: "userDefined"});
```

But if the contact hasn't yet had a custom field created, it fails.
I tried this:

```
var uDef = new People.newUserDefined();
thisResult.person.userDefined.push(uDef);
thisResult.person.clientData[0].key ="HandymanCustID";
thisResult.person.clientData[0].value = "0066";
```

The push operation fails.
Is this possible to do?
I really just want to be able to assign my own ID# to each client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that about `But if the contact hasn't yet had a custom field created, it fails. I tried this:`, in this case, the property of `userDefined` does not exist. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In this case, how about modifying it as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
let query = "Joe Smith"; 
var found = People.People.searchContacts(
  { 
    "query": query,   
    "readMask": "names,userDefined"
  }); 
thisResult = found.results[0];

// I modified the below script.
var newUserDefinedValue = { key: "HandymanCustID", value: "0066" }; // This is from your script.
var resource = {
  userDefined: [...(thisResult.person.userDefined || []), newUserDefinedValue],
  etag: thisResult.person.etag
};
People.People.updateContact(resource, thisResult.person.resourceName, { updatePersonFields: "userDefined" });
```

- In this modification, when `userDefined` is existing, the new value of `newUserDefinedValue` is added to `userDefined`. On the other hand, when `userDefined` does not exist, the new value of `newUserDefinedValue` is created to `userDefined`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.updateContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact)

Comment: Thank you for this. It gets me closer, but I don't understand what's going on in the lines var resource = {...}.  And the documentation says "The request body contains an instance of Person" but "resource" here isn't.

Also, it seems to always ADD a userDefined field. Is it possible to always write to userDefined[0] (the first one)? Can a userDefined field be removed?`

Comment: On the question about whether you can always write to userDefined[0] even if userDefined already exists, I just removed the spread syntax like so:  

var resource = {
  userDefined: [newUserDefinedValue],
  etag: thisResult.person.etag
};

That writes to userDefined[0] but (of course) removes any other userDefined fields.

Comment: @Robert M. Thank you for replying. About `It gets me closer`, I thought that my proposed modification can achieve your goal. So, can I ask you about the detail of the difference between my proposed modifiction and your expected result?

Comment: @Robert M. About `but I don't understand what's going on in the lines var resource = {...}.`, the reason for your issue of `But if the contact hasn't yet had a custom field created, it fails. I tried this:` is due to the property of `userDefined` does not exist. So, in my modification, when `userDefined` is existing, the new value of `newUserDefinedValue` is added to `userDefined`. On the other hand, when `userDefined` does not exist, the new value of `newUserDefinedValue` is created to `userDefined`. If you cannot understand my English, I apologize.

Comment: @Robert M. About `That writes to userDefined[0] but (of course) removes any other userDefined fields.`, so, I proposed the above modification like `userDefined: [...(thisResult.person.userDefined || []), newUserDefinedValue],`. In this case, when `userDefined` is existing, the new value of `newUserDefinedValue` is added to `userDefined`. On the other hand, when `userDefined` does not exist, the new value of `newUserDefinedValue` is created to `userDefined`.I apologize for this proposal.

Comment: No, don't apologize! And your English is fine! This has been very, very helpful. There's just so much else I don't know so I've been working on implementing this for what I need all day.

Comment: @Robert M. Thank you for replying and checking my script. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.